# ObserveOnDispatcher throws exception

Tags: multithreading, system.reactive

When I create a new `Timer Observable` from a thread other than primary thread, and I call `ObserveOnDispatcher` I get the following error

> Current thread has no Dispatcher associated with it

I found a few similar discussions online, one guy suggested to use `DispatcherScheduler.Instance` in `ObserveOn` instead. It works but here is the interesting part.

The following code gives you the warning that `Instance` property is obsolete and we should use `Current` property

```
var something = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler.Instance)
```

When I change it to use 'DispatcherScheduler.Current', I get the same exception as I was getting on `ObserveOnDispatcher`.

What is the most effective way to **create** an `Observable.Timer` while not in a primary thread, and observe that on Dispatcher ?

Comment: Can you try `.ObserveOn(instanceOfWpfFormOrControl)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ReactiveUI, you should never use `ObserveOnDispatcher`, always `ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)`. Also, the `Timer` method itself takes an `IScheduler` which would be better than using `ObserveOn` here

Comment: MainThreadScheduler doesn't seem to be working properly when invoking App.Shutdown, I have to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)Shutdown)